# Fourier transform evaluation

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and
$h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & ,|x|<1\\ 
0 & ,|x|\geq 1
\end{array}\right.$

I want to find the Fourier transform , $\hat{h}(\xi).$

Here is how I proceed
 $$\hat{h}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x)e^{-i\xi\cdot x}dx=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{|x|<1}e^{-i\xi\cdot x}dx$$
 where $\xi\cdot x=\sum_{k=1}^n\xi_kx_k$ and $dx=dx_1\ldots dx_n$

I need some hints on how to evaluate the integral $$\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{|x|<1}e^{-i\xi\cdot x}dx$$

Comment: Don't you have here $e^{-i\xi\cdot x}\mathrm dx=\prod_{k=1}^ne^{-i\xi_k x_k}\mathrm dx_k$?

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache. This is right but not adapted to the prevailing symmetry. Hyperspherical coordinates should do the trick. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspherical_coordinates#Hyperspherical_coordinates

Comment: @ Urgje.My problem is to find the trick that makes the integral simple. I looked at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ , but still I can't fix the problem. Please help me in this regard.